# django reusing html block for different for loop in the same template

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

I have three conditions to a given object, *1. to start*, *2. started*, and *3. finished*. 
I filter the objects in view itself and send three variables to the template - 
`tostart_objects`, `started_objects`, and `finished_objects`.

Now I loop through the three for loops in the html template as follows:

```
{% for obj in tostart_objects %}
// chunk of html template to display all the object 
{% endfor %}

{% for obj in started_objects %}
// similar chunk of html template as above
{% endfor %}

{% for obj in finished_objects %}
// similar chunk of html template as above
{% endfor %}
```

Instead of putting the same chunk of code, can I not reuse them at three different places?
How can this be done? Please let me know, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way of doing this would be to put the chunk of HTML in a separate template file, and use `{% include %}` to include it within each loop. Building on that, you could define the whole loop as an inclusion template tag that takes the object list as a parameter.

Alternatively, you could concatenate the three lists in your view, and just loop through the result.

Comment: +1 [template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags) documentation reference

Comment: This is of course a workaround, but still there is a feature missing in Django templating system. If I only ever use it in a single template, why have another file to depend on? Why can't I see the code all at once, preferably at the site of the first usage?